# How are the actions wired to reducers in Redux/Este

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using [Este starter kit](https://github.com/este/este) to build a universal react app (it uses `react-redux` and `react-router`. Looking at the example on [NewTodo component](https://github.com/este/este/blob/master/src/browser/todos/NewTodo.react.js) I can understand that `connect` is used to wire the action to the component.

```
export default connect(null, { addTodo })(NewTodo);
```

But what I am not following is how the [reducer](https://github.com/este/este/blob/master/src/common/todos/reducer.js) is wired?

How are the reducers generally wired in Redux applications?

Comment: In that particular example, this file: https://github.com/este/este/blob/master/src/common/configureReducer.js is where it 'connects' to redux

Comment: But how is the reducer fired? That's the part I don't understand. As in where is the entry point for the reducer?

Comment: In very, very basic terms, your `Action` will `dispatch` a call. The `dispatch` function will hit your reducer. The reducer then returns a new state object.

Comment: But where is this dispatch call happening? The only reference I can see to `dispatch` is (here)[https://github.com/este/este/blob/master/src/common/configureMiddleware.js#L19]. But I am not sure what it does exactly

Comment: It looks like this boilerplate is using middleware to dispatch. http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The todos reducers or any other component reducer will eventually be imported in a root reducers. and this root reducer can be a representation of your whole redux state tree. In your case, it is [this file](https://github.com/este/este/blob/master/src/common/configureReducer.js)

This root reducer is then used when you create your store ([this file](https://github.com/este/este/blob/master/src/common/configureStore.js)). Every time when you dispatches an action, store will broadcast this action to all the reducers (including its sub-reducers). and if the `action.type` matches, then the reducer will handle this action accordingly.